# Difference between month calculator in salesforce formula field

Tags: salesforce, apex

I have two dates
1.statdate : 12-11-2022
2.enddate. : 02-20-2023

if the start date is **1-15th** day then the result should be the current month ex: `mm-dd-yyyy[12-11-2022]` Then December 1st
if the start date is **16th-31st** day then the result should be the current month EX: `mm-dd-yyyy[12-22-2022]` Then January 1st.

if the EndDate  is 1-15th day then the result should be the current month+1 EX: `mm-dd-yyyy[02-11-2022]` Then January 31st
if the EndDate  is 16-31sh day then the result should be the current month+1 EX: `mm-dd-yyyy[02-20-2022]` Then Feb 28th

input **start date result:** December 1st
input **end date result:** Feb 28th
Result[3] which is three months from the start date to the end date.

Can we do this in the formula field? I am able to do it in apex it worked but I was unable to do it in the formula field any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ROUND(((IF(DAY(Return_To_Work__c) <= 15, DATE( YEAR(Return_To_Work__c) ,
MONTH(Return_To_Work__c) -1,(DAY(Return_To_Work__c)- 
 DAY(Return_To_Work__c)+
 28 + MOD(((MONTH(Return_To_Work__c) -1) + 
  FLOOR((MONTH(Return_To_Work__c) -1)/8)), 2) + MOD(2, 
  (MONTH(Return_To_Work__c) -1)) + 2 * FLOOR(1/(MONTH(Return_To_Work__c) 
  -1))))
 ,IF(DAY(Return_To_Work__c) >= 16,DATE( YEAR(Return_To_Work__c) 
 ,MONTH(Return_To_Work__c),(DAY(Return_To_Work__c)- 
  DAY(Return_To_Work__c)+28 + MOD(((MONTH(Return_To_Work__c)) + 
    FLOOR((MONTH(Return_To_Work__c))/8)), 2) + MOD(2, 
  (MONTH(Return_To_Work__c))) + 2 * 
   FLOOR(1/(MONTH(Return_To_Work__c))))),NULL)) -
  IF(DAY(First_Day_Of_Leave__c) <= 15, DATE( YEAR(First_Day_Of_Leave__c) 
  , MONTH(First_Day_Of_Leave__c) ,(DAY(First_Day_Of_Leave__c)- 
  DAY(First_Day_Of_Leave__c)+1)),IF(DAY(First_Day_Of_Leave__c) >= 
    16,DATE( YEAR(First_Day_Of_Leave__c) 
  ,MONTH(First_Day_Of_Leave__c)+1,(DAY(First_Day_Of_Leave__c)- 
   DAY(First_Day_Of_Leave__c)+1)),NULL)))/30),0)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).